# C# configuration getsection returns null even when section exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the following line of code the 'loggingConfig' is returning null and getting the specified exception. The config section is available in appsettings.json. but still having this error

```
var loggingConfig = appConfiguration.GetSection("logging")?.Get<LoggingConfig>();
if (loggingConfig == null)
   throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("logging Config not specified");
```

Model

```
public class LoggingConfig
{
    public string LogFilePath { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

appsetting.json

```
{
    "logging": {
        "logFilePath": "log/log-.txt",
        "applicationName": "API",
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "Debug": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Error"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show how you configure the configuration, where is your .ConfigureAppConfiguration() method?

Comment: have you tried debugging? Check if appConfiguration contains entries from appsettings.json. Code itself looks fine

Comment: `appConfiguration` type must be `ConfigurationManager`.can access with `builder.Configuration `

Comment: How do you inject `appConfiguration`? Could you pls share more details?